# Untransferable token percentage

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I've seen multiple ICO's make total token supply untransferable and understand the purpose why. Now, is it possible to make an individual contributor's token balance transferable in portions? e.g. 5% every 7 days.

Comment: Yes. Where's your code so far, and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at how to keep tracking of each % unlocked transferable individual balance. E.g. I'm the owner of the sale, I've transferred 10000 tokens to you. You can see all 10000 tokens in your wallet but only 5% is transferable per 7 days. Now if I want, I should be able to give u another 100k which follows same 'cooldown'.

Comment: This blog post should help: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/06/09/reversible-ether/.

Comment: I'm looking more for something similar to a pauseableToken but a partial pauseable version

Comment: Are you saying the blog post didn't help? The sections "Keeping Track of Pending Transfers" and "Finalizing Transfers" are the most applicable. Just put 95% directly in `balanceOf` and keep the other 5% pending.

Comment: Yes the blog didn't really help much, I'm trying to have the balanceof continuously stay 100% of a transfer initially all frozen and a % of this 100% will be unfrozen gradually, however the balanceOf will remain 100% transfers will just revert if the amount surpasses the unfrozen amount.

Comment: I would recommend against that, but you can certainly reverse what the blog post does. (Put it all in `balanceOf` and separately track a `frozenBalanceOf`.)

Comment: Ok, what would you recommend if token transfer from an admin should be periodically transferable/released over a certain duration (similar to vesting in ICO's) while transfers from other users should be normal/full amount with no pending/release schema?

Comment: You keep introducing new requirements. :-) But my recommendation would still be to do what the blog post does. Keep a set of pending transfers, and adjust `balanceOf` according to how long it's been since each transfer. The blog post used an explicit finalize step, but you could embed that in a `balanceOf` function and `transfer`/`transferFrom` functions. (Just watch out for gas limits... automatically updating those balances would require a loop over all pending transfers.)